# Why time squared ($t^2$) vs distance ($s$) graph is a straight line?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, distance

In the formula for kinematic constant acceleration $a$, where $s$ is displacement, $v_{i}$ initial velocity and $t$ time:

$s=v_{i}t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$

Why is that the graph $t^2$ vs $s$ happens to be a straight line?

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) As it is now, your question is hard to understand because it does not contain enough information. Try elaborating your question a bit.

Comment: Your graph shows $T^2$ (which is probably periodic time) against $m/kg$. It does not show $t^2$ vs distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kinematic constant acceleration $a$ equation is

$s = v_{\rm i}t + \frac 12a t^2$

Where $s$ is the distance and $t$ is the time.

If the initial speed is zero, $v_{\rm i}=0$, then the equation can be rearranged to become $t^2=2s$ which is of the form of the general equation of a straight line $y=mx+c$.

So if $t^2$ is plotted against $s$ you should get a straight line of gradient $m = 2$ and intercept on the $t^2$ axis $c=0\,.$